# Unexpected response code 412 while requesting images with volley

Tags: android, image, networking, android-volley

We are currently trying to get volley running to load images into NetworkViews.

The images are requested and loaded by volley in this row:

```
holder.image.setImageUrl(image.getUrl(), imageManager.getImageLoader());
```

On the device of my co-worker it works smooth, but on mine and a third test device we are getting a bunch of volley errors and **some** images stay blank (which images differs on both devices).

The images are all on the same server and we see absolutly no reason why some images load and some don't or why it should be device dependent which images load.

```
09-17 14:15:51.660: E/Volley(19440): [1087] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 412 for xxxx
```

So how can we fix this and what can be the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Request to clear the cache before `rQueue.getCache().clear();`
I looked at the data capture under Volley submitted if the cache, then added two Http header information`If-None-Match & If-Modified-Since`,These two parameters to update the information used to determine whether the cache, if the webserver does not support, it returns an error code 412

Comment: Where should i add this line in `AppController` ? In which method?

Answer (score 0):

```
imageLoader.get(image_url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(viewHolder.status_pic, R.drawable.icon_loading, R.drawable.icon_error));
```

its better to use a listener when getting image with volley but the Error 412 - Precondition Failed

Why it occurs

The server does not meet one of the preconditions that the requester put on the request. i.e.,The header of the request specified information about acceptable files that is not applicable to the requested file.

Comment: But we don't change any preconditions and all images are png files on the same server, so why are some getting loaded and some don't? Also why are there only problems on some devices? Does volley produce device dependend request headers?

Comment: do either of you guys have any clue abotu my issue? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009312/how-to-detect-412-precondition-failed-errors-in-android-webview-url